# Restarting Azures Kubernetes Cluster VM causes GPU problems

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Got my pod up and working, used the GPU, everything was fine, then I restarted the AKS-VM in the portal. When doing this and restarting the pod it hung on *pending* forever. When I ran `kubectl describe pod myFirstPod` it says `1 Insufficient alpha.kubernetes.io/nvidia-gpu`.

What am I doing wrong, or what is wrong? Do I have to delete and recreate the cluster again?

Comment: Might be a bug. Did you try deleting the pod?

Comment: Thank you for replying Rico! I ran `kubectl delete pod myFirstPod`, and tried to apply a new job, but it did not work (Is that the right way to delete it?). I deleted the AKS VM and built a new one, after applying the job with `kubectl apply -f myFirstPod-gpu.yaml` I finally got `CreatingContainer` and a few minutes later `running`.

Comment: You could try the command `kubectl delete deployment name` to delete the deployment of the pod.

Comment: I contacted MS about this, will post the response here.